# Clang-Format: recombine string literals

Tags: c++, automated-refactoring, clang-format

Is there a way to get clang-format to turn this:

```cpp
function_name("a very very "                | <-- column limit
              "very very "                  |
              "long string");               |
```

into this:

```cpp
function_name("a very very very very long"  |
              " string");                   |
```

It will happily break string literals over the limit, but I can't seem to get it to recombine.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, did not find how to do it with `clang-format`. In the end, went with the following Python script:

```py
filename = "/path/to/file"
content = ""
with open(filename,'r') as infile:
  content = infile.read()
  content = re.sub('"\n\s*"', '', content)
with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
  outfile.write(content)
```

The regex on line 5 deletes a double quote followed by a newline, whitespace, and a new double quote. For me this worked.

Later on, the following `clang-format` option may be useful to not break string literals again:

```
BreakStringLiterals = false
```